# Clojure CLI with multiple subcommands

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface

I have written some libraries in clojure that scrape some search results as a small side project. I want to use these libraries in a cli where there would be a few different scripts that could run, like:

- collect, run scraping job,
- browse, browse previously collected results,
- search-config, add or remove search parameters.

I would like to implement the solution as a command line interface as follows:

```
cljscrape [general flags] subcommand [flags] [args]
```

I know you can use the packages stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341154/building-a-clojure-app-with-a-command-line-interface), but it seems to only parse flags. If anyone could recommend how to structure the project, or a package that will allow me to best imitate the template format that would be awesome!

P.S

I am quite new to clojure so I apologise if I say anything stupid. Thanks! :)

Comment: https://github.com/l3nz/cli-matic

Answer (score 4):

An example using [babashka CLI](https://github.com/babashka/cli):

```clj
(def args ["--general-flag" "subcommand" "--flag" "arg"])

(require '[babashka.cli :as cli])
```

The var `args` contains some example arguments. Normally you would get these from `*command-line-args*` or the arguments passed to a `-main` function.

First parse the general options:

```clj
(def parsed (cli/parse-args args {:coerce {:general-flag :boolean}}))
;;=> {:opts {:general-flag true}, :args ["subcommand" "--flag" "arg"]}
```

Note that in `:opts` we now have the parsed general options and the rest of the arguments, still unparsed, are saved inside `:args`.

When we parse those `:args` in turn again with `parse-args`, we get the subcommands, options and arguments:

```clj
(cli/parse-args (:args parsed) {:coerce {:flag :boolean}})
;;=> {:cmds ["subcommand"], :opts {:flag true}, :args ["arg"]}
```

So you can use this two-step process to support general arguments.
To dispatch on the subcommands, you can read the documentation [here](https://github.com/babashka/cli#subcommands). You can see the dispatch function in action in the [neil](https://github.com/babashka/neil) project.
For this example, it would be something like:

```clj
(def dispatch-table
  [{:cmds ["subcommand"] :fn handle-subcommand}])

(cli/dispatch dispatch-table (:args parsed) {:coerce {:flag :boolean}})
```

and function `handle-subcommand` would then be called with the arguments `{:opts {:flag true}, :args ["arg"]}`.